# Pass simple string phrases to an alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm developing an Alexa skill and want to pass simple utterances like "*How much are five oranges*" to it.

My idea was to define utterances like

```
how much are {amount} {articleName}
```

with the slots amount of type `NUMBER` and articleName of type `AMAZON.SearchQuery`

But `AMAZON.SearchQuery` cannot be combined with other slot types. Thus, are there other ways to pass simple, non typed-strings like article names to a skill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a custom slot type:

[Overview of custom slot types](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/create-and-edit-custom-slot-types.html#overview-of-custom-slot-types)

Create your custom slot type for `articleName` and just add a number of example slot values. This should work for you.

If the slot value can be 1 word as well as 2 words - make sure you add examples for both.

Once you've set this up in the developer console, you could test it (without deploying code), using the [utterance profiler](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/test-utterances-and-improve-your-interaction-model.html#test-an-utterance).

You can then tweak / revise as needed.

Comment: This only works, if I define ALL article names previously in the custom slot type, right? This isn't possible since this can be one of millions of names out of a growing database/API. The help isn't quite clear here - only mention to give some example entries (not all) in the custom slot type.

Comment: No, you don't need to add all of the possible values. However, if the values could be made up of 1, 2, or even 3 words. Make sure  you have examples like that too.

Answer (score 1):

A custom slot type is not the equivalent of an enumeration.

> Values outside the list are still returned if recognized by the spoken
>   language understanding system

Although input to the slot type is weighted towards the values in the list, it is **not constrained to just the items on the list**.

[Ref here.](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/create-and-edit-custom-slot-types.html)